# Find Same Word But Replace With Different Words In Different Files

Tags: notepad++

I would really appreciate any help with this.

I have 10 .txt Files & All have the **same** word 'KEYWORD' in them.

**Now what I want is the Following:**

'KEYWORD' In File 1 Should Be Replaced By 'KEYWORD1'

'KEYWORD' In File 2 Should Be Replaced By 'KEYWORD2'

'KEYWORD' In File 3 Should Be Replaced By 'KEYWORD3'

'KEYWORD' In File 4 Should Be Replaced By 'KEYWORD4'

'KEYWORD' In File 5 Should Be Replaced By 'KEYWORD5'

& So On...

So is there a way to do this?

I don't have any programming background, so it would be great to get some free software which can manage this. I don't think its possible with NP++ since it will simply replace with same word (& that is not what I want).

If freeware is not available, then willing to learn some basic programming (which language?) if that helps in solving this problem.

**Again, any help would be appreciated.**

Regards

Comment: File 1, File 2... are these the actual names of the files in question ?

Comment: If File 1, File 2 are indeed the names of the files, it is unlikely that this can be done in Notepad++. You probably want to use a proper language like Python for instance.

Comment: Actual Name of Files is 0.txt, 1.txt, 2.txt & so on. What should be file names if this is to be done through Notepad++? Would Appreciate a response.